# Kotlin Flow - Replacement for callbackFlow

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, callback, kotlin-flow

I am working on an Android project where `MVVM` is the architecture being used. There is a use case where a `Flow` in my `Repository` needs to be updated based on the results of a callback which is triggered when something in my Data Source changes. The most appropriate choice for this problem seems to be `callbackFlow`. However, it is [still experimental](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/callback-flow.html). I am very tempted to use `callbackFlow`, however, I understand that any future changes might break some code and I don't want that to happen in a production app. Considering the above scenario, what should be a replacement for `callbackFlow`? Or should I consider going ahead with `callbackFlow`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`callbackFlow` is runtime stable - it works just as it is supposed to and it exists exactly because it is exactly the right tool to use in many cases.

> I understand that any future changes might break some code and I don't want that to happen in a production app"

The only change that would affect how it functions is when upgrading your version of coroutines. That has nothing to do with runtime stability.